# Обновление списка в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Для обновления списка в RecyclerView знаю три способа.

1. notifyDataSetChanged()
2. notifyItemChanged()
3. Использовать DiffUtils.

Может кто дать совет в каких случаях, какой способ эффективнее использовать. И если есть еще какие способы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` - заставляет обновить все элементы списка, по сути перерисовывает их все, даже если не было никаких изменений в видимых в данный момент на экране элементов. Обычно используют, когда измененных элементов в списке много и сам список довольно большой.

`notifyItemChanged()` - событие изменения конкретного элемента списка, то есть по идее перерисуется только тот элемент, позицию которой передали в аргументе. Предпочтительный способ, когда мы точно знаем какие элементы в списке были изменены, тем более, по логике, если элемент в данный момент не отображается на экране, то лишний раз не будет перерисовки.

`DiffUtils` - во многих источниках советуют использовать его вместо `notifyDataSetChanged()`, но я как-то не увидел большого выигрыша, даже наоборот, производительность упала. Возможно не так реализовал, не спорю. Но тут по идее зависит от объема самого списка, при большом списке, думаю предпочтительнее `notifyDataSetChanged()`, так как в `DiffUtils` все равно нужно сравнивать поэлементно.

Comment: А я разницы между `notifyItemChanged()` и `notifyDataSetChanged()` у себя вообще не увидел. Если элемента нет на экране - то и перерисовываться сразу он не будет